# How can I kill Firefox by console?

Tags: linux, shell, process

I know I can type:

```
ps -A | grep firefox
```

I get something like:

```
6818 ?        00:04:23 firefox
```

Now I can kill it by means of:

```
kill -9 6818
```

How can it be done in one command and how can I make new command (say `kf`) that does this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

the command to script-kill processes is `pkill` and `killall`. see the wikipedia page of [`pkill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill) and [`killall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) for more details.

I will provide some examples for `pkill`. `killall` works similar to `pkill`.

```
pkill -f firefox
```

This will kill all processes which have the string 'firefox' in the command.

Note that this will kill **all** processes which have the string `firefox` in the command.

For example if you have a gedit open editing a file called firefox.txt like this:

```
$ gedit firefox.txt &
$ pgrep -fl firefox
10959 gedit firefox.txt
30077 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin
30123 /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so 30077 plugin true
```

Then doing a `pkill -f firefox` will also kill the gedit process.

You can prevent this by telling `pkill` to kill only exact matches using `pkill -x /usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin`. `killall` has the switch `-e` which has the same effect.

You can create an alias in bash:

```
alias kf='pkill -f firefox'
```

Now you can use `kf` to kill firefox.

---

nitpick: most of the time you want `kill` without `-9`. only use `kill -9` if you have tried everything else first and know what you are doing and know how to clean up afterwards.

for more explanation see this question and answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/why-not-kill-9-a-process.

also this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67166/why-does-firefox-refuse-to-die-despite-killing-it-with-pkill-9/75716#75716

Comment: Very strange.. If I kill firefox without -9 when it hangs nothing happens :S (btw I'm actually talking about windows, where the non -9 kill is the X on the window, and the -9 kill is terminate it from the task manager).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ kill $(ps -x | grep firefox | awk '{print $1}')
```

This command kills all firefox instances. From this website: [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fix-firefox-is-already-running-but-is-not-responding-error-message)

Answer (score -2):

[wmctrl](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_gracefully_kill_(close)_programs_and_processes_via_command_line) to control windows can be used

```
wmctrl -c Firefox
```